# CRM 2011 Importing managed solution overrides system view changes

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, system-views

In production environment if I change some system view, for instance "Quick Find" and add another view/find column, then if I import managed solution from my development environment, the view is overriden and I see all the columns as they appear in dev and I don't see the new added column before the import (in prod).

Any idea why the managed solution overrides my changes in prod? Why doesn't it work like with regular form fields or something like that, that managed solution doesn't override unmanaged change that I'm doing in the target organization.

Answer (score 2):

The views are defined as a part of the entity, and unlike attributes on a entity, do not support accumulative changes (If CRM currently has columns A,B,C,D, and a solution is imported that has columns B,D,E,A, how should CRM handle the import).  So views work as a last one in wins sort of auto merge.

You'll need to make your changes to the views in Dev as well so when you import your solution into prod the views look how you'd like, or create views in Prod that are not in Dev.

Comment: Not sure I understood you complitely, but for instance if in dev in quick find, I'll add all the columns of some entity to the "view columns" and to the "find columns", then when I import the entity to production, all the view/find columns that existed in production would stay as they were before the import? or the import will again override all the view/find columns that existed in production before the import?

Comment: Again, we have many clients in production and each one has different columns in the quick find view. So how can we import solution from dev so it won't override the quick find in each production client? We can't have multiple quick find views..?